# Position vectors and collinearity

Tags: vectors

The points A, B, C and D have position vectors **a**, **b**, **4b** and *k*(**a - b**) respectively. Find the value of *k* if A, C and D are collinear.

I know that $\vec AC$ = c - a is some proportion of $\vec CD$ = d -  c but cannot use this to get the answer, which the book tells me is 4/3.

Comment: What is $\bf c-a$ and $\bf d-c$ in terms of $\bf a$ and $\bf b$?

Comment: "I know that $\vec{AC}$ = c - a is some proportion of $\vec{CD}$ = d - c"  That makes no sense because there are NO numbers "a", c" and "d" in the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\vec{AC}$= 4**b**- **a** while $\vec{CD}$= k(**a**- **b**)- 4**b**= k**a**- (4+ k)**b**.  In order that that be a multiple of 4**b**- **a**, that "multiple" we must have k**a**= -p**a** and (4+ k)**b**= 4p**b**.  That is, k= -p and 4+ k= 4p.  Solve for k and p.